# ¿Es posible llenar un DataTable usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Estoy utilizando el *plugin* `DataTable` de `jQuery`. Sé que la forma normal de llenar un `DataTable` es la siguiente:

```js
function listarProformas(){
  var datos = {
    "dni" : $('#txt_dni').val(),
    "cargo" : $('#txt_cargo').val()
  }
  $('#tablaPersonal').DataTable({
    destroy : true,
      ajax: {
          url: "controlador",
          method: "POST",
          data: datos,
          dataSrc: "datos"
      },
      columns: [
          {data: "nroProforma"},
          {data: "dni"},
          {data: "nombres"},
          {data: "apellidos"},
          {data: "concepto"},
          {data: "email"},
          {data: "direccion"}
      ]
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablaPersonal" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead class="table table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>nroProforma</th>
            <th>dni</th>
            <th>Apel</th>
            <th>apellidos</th>
            <th>concepto</th>                                            
            <th>Dirección</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>direccion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

En este caso, los datos se guardan automáticamente en las columnas, pero quisiera trabajar con los datos que obtengo como respuesta del `AJAX` para agregar botones a las columnas, colocar un índice al inicio de la tabla, etc. Quiero saber si es posible llenar las columnas por `JavaScript`, mas o menos de esta manera:

```js
function listarProformas(){
  var datos = {
   "dni" : dni,
   "cargo" : cargo
  }  
  ajax: {
      url: "controlador",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json"
      success: function(data){
         $("#tablaPersonal").Datatable();
        var fila = '';
        for(var i=0; data.lenght; i++){
          fila += "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+data['nroProforma']+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data['dni']+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data['concepto']+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data['Dirección']+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data['Email']+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data['direccion']+"</td>"+
                  "</tr>";
        }
        $("#tablaPersonal").append(fila);
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablaPersonal" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead class="table table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>nroProforma</th>
            <th>dni</th>
            <th>apellidos</th>
            <th>concepto</th>                                            
            <th>Dirección</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>direccion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Porque me resulta más fácil manipular el contenido de las filas que inserto. Intenté algo similar a esto último, pero la `DataTable` se crea por separado y no puedo utilizar sus propiedades como "búsqueda" y "ordenamiento".

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, a vos el segundo método te trae correctamente los datos que estabas esperando. Pero el tema es que no te aparece el buscador, ni el paginador, ni el seleccionador de cantidad de elementos, correcto?

Comment: Correcto, es como si se creara una tabla diferente. en la vista, me aparecen dos tablas, la primera aparece el <thead> del datatable y en las columnas me aparece "Registers not found" y más abajo me muestra toda la data pero de manera separada

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable` te permite usar múltiples tipos de *data source* para alimentar a tu tabla. En tu código usas una `URL` que internamente será llamada por `AJAX`, pero también es posible usar un `array` que tengas declarado directamente en el código:

```js
var datos = [
  {
    name: "Alejandro",
    username: "alejandro",
    email: "alejandro@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Julio",
    username: "julillo",
    email: "julio@yahoo.es"
  },
  {
    name: "Pedro",
    username: "peter",
    email: "peter@gmail.com"
  }
];

$('#myTable').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  searching: false,
  info: false,
  data: datos,
  columns: [
    { title: "Nombre", data: "name" },
    { title: "Usuario", data: "username" },
    { title: "Correo", data: "email" }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
</table>
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta, puedes leer directamente los datos por `AJAX`, manipularlos y después usarlos como *data source*. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente snippet, leeré por `AJAX` un `JSON` de [@typicode](https://github.com/typicode) con [la siguiente estructura](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users), lo modificaré para añadir una columna con las iniciales del nombre y añadiré una columna con botones que tienen como [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) el nombre de cada usuario y después usaré esos datos modificados como *data source* de la tabla:

```js
$.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function (json) {

  var data = json.map(function (fila) {
    var iniciales = fila.name.replace(/^(\w)[\w\.]* (\w)\w* ?(\w)?.*$/, "$1$2$3");
    return $.extend({iniciales: iniciales, boton: "<button class='botonTabla' data-name='" + fila.name +"'>Click</button>"}, fila);
  });

  $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        info: false,
        data: data,
        columns: [
            { title: "Iniciales", data: "iniciales" },
            { title: "Usuario", data: "username" },
            { title: "", data: "boton" }
        ]
    } );
    
    $('#myTable').on("click", ".botonTabla", function () {
      console.log( this.dataset.name );
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo así:

- Creas el `DataTable` (*es recomendable definir la configuración de columnas*).
- Al recibir los datos utilizas:

  - [`table.rows().remove()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove()) para borrar las filas existentes.
  - [`table.rows.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) para agregar las filas.
- **Importante**: Es importante que el **nombre de las propiedades** de los registros devueltos en la llamada `ajax` coincida exactamente con el **valor en `data` de las columnas**

#### Ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablaPersonal" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%;"></table>
<script>
let table = $('#tablaPersonal').Datatable({
  columns: [
    {data: "nroProforma", title: 'Nro. Proforma'},
    {data: "dni", title: 'DNI'},
    {data: "nombres", title: 'Nombres'},
    {data: "apellidos", title: 'Apellidos'},
    {data: "concepto", title: 'Concepto'},
    {data: "email", title: 'Email'},
    {data: "direccion", title: 'Dirección'}
  ]
});

function listarProformas() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "controlador",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      // Limpiamos
      table.rows().remove();
      // Cargamos
      table.rows.add(data).draw();
    }
  });
}
</script>
```